# Can't Open Android SDK Manager using `android` Command on Terminal

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, android-sdk-tools

I'm unable to open the Android SDK Manager using the `android` command on terminal.

I am following https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

And I download and installed Android Studio and Installed HAXM and AVD with the given steps.

Now I need to

3. Install the Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) SDK

However, I am not seeing the same screen as the documentation when accessing the SDK manager via Android studio.

"The SDK Manager can also be found within the Android Studio "Preferences" menu, under Appearance & Behavior → System Settings → Android SDK."

So I am using the Android command on terminal to open the SDK Manager; however, I'm receiving the following error.

```
/usr/local/bin/android: line 3: /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.3.4/tools/android: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/android: line 3: exec: /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.3.4/tools/android: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

**I'm curious as to why is this happening. How can it be resolved?**

Comment: check that the file exists by looking at each directory in the path, you may have enetered a typo or wrong version number

Comment: I anticipate that is the case. How should I fix that?

Comment: as you go through each directory see what the actual name is, eg maybe you have version 25.4.0 instead of 24.3.4?

Comment: This is a dumb question, but does one access /usr/local/bin/android? And btw I believe your example is the case.

Answer (score 0):

[image: insure that show Package Details is selected in every screen]

insure that show Package Details is selected in every screen